# Algorithm for swapping of odd lettered string

Tags: algorithm

I am new to computer science and was solving a question in brilliant.org. 
Suppose a function with an input of the string "ABCDEFG". (A is in the 1st position, B is in the 2nd position, and so on.)

Step 1. Set loop = 0

Step 2. Add 1 to loop

Step 3. Swap the letter at position Loop  with the letter at position Loop+2

Step 4. If Loop<4 then  go to Step 2.

Step 5. End.

What will be the string at Step 5?

I had a problem with swapping because of the odd numbered string. Can anyone explain me the logic behind looping of the last letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming position starts from `0`.

```
ABCDEFG

1. loop = 0
2. loop = 1
3. swap B and D => ADCBEFG
4. loop < 4 => true, go to step 2

2. loop = 2
3. swap C and E => ADEBCFG
4. loop < 4 => true, got to step 2

2. loop = 3
3. swap B and F => ADEFCBG
4. loop < 4 => true, got to step 2

2. loop = 4
3. swap C and G => ADEFGBC
4. loop < 4 => false, go to 5
5. end
```

Comment: Understood! My mistake was that I was swapping all letters in every loop. For eg: first with the third and second with the fourth and so on every time. I should've considered swapping two letters for one loop. Thank you and the answer is CDEFABG. By swapping A and C in the first loop and continuing it further.